# Unexpected app crash when managing large ammounts of data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a Service that is going to synchronize around 7,000 database records (from MySQL to SQLite via some asmx webservices) and around 100 MB in files every day automatically. Right now I have only test data of various days, Aprox 400,000 records and 500 MB of data.

I start my service on my MainActivity with the following code:
`SyncFromWeb = new Intent(context, SyncFromWeb.class);
startService(SyncFromWeb);`

My Service checks the database every minute to see if it's time to synchronize and does the download of the data. Besides that I have two Intent Services running to synchronize from the tablet to the central database. One only calls webservices (the calls are stored on a SQLite table) and the other synchronizes images that are taken within the application. I use this approach to not slow down the data update if the user takes too many pictures.

My service looks like this (part of):

```
public class SyncFromWeb extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "Sync Data From Web";
private boolean isRunning = false;
private List<Pair<String, Object>> ParameterList = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Object>>();

private final String WebServiceURL = Constants.URL_BASE + "Android_DAL.asmx";
private final String NameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";

private Handler Mainhandler;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    isRunning = true;
    Mainhandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final Context context = this;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting Sync From Web Service");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // boolean Variables declaration

            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

            SimpleDateFormat DateTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
            String ExecutionDateTime = "";
            Date CurrentDateTime = new Date();
            Date NextExecutionDateTime = new Date();

            while(ExecutionDateTime.trim().equals("")) {
                ExecutionDateTime  = GetTaskExecutionTime(GetManufacturerSerialNumber());

                if(ExecutionDateTime.trim().equals("")) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { Log.d(TAG, "Exception while getting Execution Task Time. Details: " + ex.getMessage()); }
                }
            }

    // Not all the tablets are going to synchronize
            isRunning = !ExecutionDateTime.equals("NO SYNC");

            while(isRunning) {
                try {
                    CurrentDateTime = new Date();
                    NextExecutionDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.parse(ExecutionDateTime);
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "");
                }

                if(CurrentDateTime.compareTo(NextExecutionDateTime) > 0) {
                    ShowToast("Running scheduled syncronization from Web Database...");

                    //... Download data routines

                    if(WorkListDataDone && WorkListStageDataDone && WorkListInspectionPointDataDone && WorkListInspectionResultDataDone && WorkListInspectionResultPictureDataDone && InspectionKitDataDone && ListsDataDone) {
                        //.. Booleans set to false 
                        SetNextSynchronizationTime(GetManufacturerSerialNumber());

//.. Calculate local next sync time, current sync time plus 24 hours
                        ShowToast("Today's synchronization finished...");
                    }
                    db.close();
                }
                else {

                    try {
            // If it's not time to execute, check back in one minute
                        Thread.sleep(1000*60);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { Log.d(TAG, "Exception on Thread.Sleep."); }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    isRunning = false;

    Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed");
}

private String GetTaskExecutionTime(String TabletSerialNumber) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_Tablet_Get";
    String ExecutionDateTime = "NO SYNC";

    //.. Retrieve sync date time from Db

    return ExecutionDateTime;
}

private void SetNextSynchronizationTime(String TabletSerialNumber) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_Tablet_Update_Sync_Time";
    //.. Update next sync date time to db
}

private boolean UpdateListData(DatabaseHandler SQLLiteHandler) {
    try {
        ShowToast("Updating List data from Web Database...");

        //.... Normal processing, no problems
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ShowToast("An error ocurred while synchronizing Lists data from Web Database. Retrying...");
        Log.d(TAG, "An Exception occurred on CreateListData. Details: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private Pair<List<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List>, List<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List>> GetListsList() throws Exception {
    List<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List> ReturnToDeleteList = new ArrayList<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List>();
    List<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List> ReturnToInsertList = new ArrayList<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List>();


//... Normal processing, no problems

    return new Pair<List<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List>, List<com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.obj.List>>(ReturnToDeleteList, ReturnToInsertList);
}

// Function to retrieve the various chunks of data from the webservice
private Pair<Boolean, JSONArray> GetWorklistData(String MethodName, String FromDateTime, String TableName, int StartingIndex, int RowQuantity) {
    JSONArray returnJSONArray = null;
    Boolean succesfullExecution = false;

    ParameterList.clear();
    ParameterList.add(new Pair<String, Object>("FromDateTime", FromDateTime));
    ParameterList.add(new Pair<String, Object>("LimitFrom", StartingIndex));
    ParameterList.add(new Pair<String, Object>("Offset", RowQuantity));

    SoapSerializationEnvelope SOAPEnvelope;

    SOAPEnvelope = CreateSOAPConnection("http://tempuri.org/", WebServiceURL, MethodName, ParameterList);

    try {
        SoapPrimitive SOAPJson = (SoapPrimitive) SOAPEnvelope.getResponse();
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(SOAPJson.toString());
        returnJSONArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray(TableName);
        succesfullExecution = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ShowToast("An error ocurred while retrieving the Worklist data from Web Database. Retrying...");
        Log.d(TAG, "An Exception occurred on GetWorklistData. Details: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    return new Pair<Boolean, JSONArray>(succesfullExecution, returnJSONArray);
}

private boolean UpdateWorkListData(DatabaseHandler db, String FromDateTime) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_WorklistData";
    String TableName = "worklist";
    int StartingIndex = 0;
    int RowQuantity = 1000;
    boolean Succesfull = false;

    SQLiteDatabase SQLLiteDb = db.GetSQLiteInstance();

    while(true) {
        Pair<Boolean, JSONArray> WorklistDataFromWeb = GetWorklistData(MethodName, FromDateTime, TableName, StartingIndex, RowQuantity);

        if(WorklistDataFromWeb.first && (WorklistDataFromWeb.second == null || WorklistDataFromWeb.second.length() == 0)) {
            Succesfull = true;
            break;
        }

        JSONArray jsonArrayWorklist =  WorklistDataFromWeb.second;

        try {
            ShowToast("Updating Worklist data from Web Database...");

            for(int i=0; i < jsonArrayWorklist.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayWorklist.getJSONObject(i);

                db.DeleteALLWorkList(SQLLiteDb, jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                db.AddWorkList(SQLLiteDb, new WorkList(jsonObject.getString("ID"),
                                jsonObject.getString("TabletSerial"),
                                jsonObject.getString("SAP_No"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Serial"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Unit"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Model"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Number"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Customer_Name"),
                                jsonObject.getInt("Line_ID"),
                                jsonObject.getInt("List_ID"))
                );
            }

            StartingIndex += RowQuantity;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ShowToast("An error ocurred while Synchronizing the Worklist data from Web Database. Retrying...");
            Log.d(TAG, "An Exception occurred on UpdateWorkListData. Details: " + ex.getMessage());
            break;
        }
    }

    SQLLiteDb.close();

    return Succesfull;
}

private boolean UpdateWorkListStageData(DatabaseHandler db, String FromDateTime) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_WorklistStageData";
    String TableName = "worklist_stage";
    int StartingIndex = 0;
    int RowQuantity = 1000;
    boolean Succesfull = false;

// Same logic as above method

    return Succesfull;
}

private boolean UpdateWorkListInspectionPointData(DatabaseHandler db, String FromDateTime) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_WorklistInspectionPointData";
    String TableName = "worklist_inspectionpoint";
    int StartingIndex = 0;
    int RowQuantity = 500;
    boolean Succesfull = false;

// Samle logic as above method. This method has a smaller chunk because there are many columns and it's the biggest table

    return Succesfull;
}

private boolean UpdateWorkListInspectionResultData(DatabaseHandler db, String FromDateTime) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_WorklistInspectionResultData";
    String TableName = "worklist_inspectionresult";
    int StartingIndex = 0;
    int RowQuantity = 500;
    boolean Succesfull = false;

// Same logic as above method.

    return Succesfull;
}

private boolean UpdateWorkListInspectionResultPictureData(DatabaseHandler db, String FromDateTime) {
    String MethodName = "SyncToTablet_WorklistInspectionResultPicturesData";
    String TableName = "worklist_inspectionresultpictures";
    int StartingIndex = 0;
    int RowQuantity = 5;
    boolean Succesfull = false;

// Same logic as above method. This is a smaller chunk because the images are stored in the database, average size is of 70Kb 

    return true;
}

private boolean UpdateInspectionKitData(DatabaseHandler db, String FromDateTime) {
//.. Do a bunch of stuff, nested loops, each item of second loop creates a file            
CreateInspectionKitFile(jsonObject.getString("Kit_Document").toLowerCase(), jsonObject.getString("Kit_FileName").toLowerCase(), jsonObject.getString("Kit_SAP_No").toLowerCase());

        //.. Rest of code
    return  true;
}

private void CreateInspectionKitFile(String FileName, String ServerFileName, String SubFolder) {
    File SDCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File InspectionKitFileFolder = new File(SDCardPath + "/QIRS/" + SubFolder + "/");
    File InspectionKitFile = new File(SDCardPath + "/QIRS/" + SubFolder + "/" + FileName);

    if(!InspectionKitFile.exists()) {
        ParameterList.clear();
        ParameterList.add(new Pair<String, Object>("FileName", ServerFileName));

        SoapSerializationEnvelope SOAPEnvelope;
        SOAPEnvelope = CreateSOAPConnection("http://tempuri.org/", WebServiceURL, "InspectionKit_GetFile", ParameterList);

        try {
            SoapPrimitive SOAPJson = (SoapPrimitive) SOAPEnvelope.getResponse();

            byte[] FileData = Base64.decode(SOAPJson.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            try {
                InspectionKitFileFolder.mkdirs();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(InspectionKitFile);
                BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                outputStream.write(FileData);
                outputStream.close();
                fos.close();

                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Finalizing File Data for " + ServerFileName + ".");
                        FileData = null;
                    }
                    catch (Throwable tex) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Exception while Finalizing File Data Array. Details: "  + tex.getMessage());
                    }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "An Exception ocurred on CreateLocalInspectionKitDetail while Creating the File " + FileName + ". Details: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "An Exception ocurred on CreateInspectionKitDetail. Details: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

// Retrieve the tablet serial number
private String GetManufacturerSerialNumber() {
    String SerialNumber = null;
    //.. GEt serial number routine
    return SerialNumber;
}

private SoapSerializationEnvelope CreateSOAPConnection(String NameSpace, String WebServiceURL, String MethodName, List<Pair<String, Object>> Parameters) {
//.. SOAP call to webservice
}

private void ListSubstraction(List<?> ItemsToDeleteList, List<?> FromList) {
    Collection ResultCollection = FromList;
    ResultCollection.removeAll(ItemsToDeleteList);
}

public void ShowToast(final String Message) {
// I was receiving an error about a Looper, this is the only case that I found a reference to Looper, that's why I removed it
//        Handler h = new Handler(SyncFromWeb.this.getMainLooper());

    Mainhandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

The service runs without a problem, I start my sync from 2015-09-01 (I don't have much data or no data on the first days) and my app crashes when I get to 2015-10-02 (by this date, there is a lot of data) since I left it running all night, it crashed and I was unable to retrieve any error (logcat continued scrolling and I don't know if I can retrieve old messages from log), so I run it again today and about 1 hour after execution I got these error messages:

```
10-15 09:58:26.320  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs D/Sync Data To Web﹕ Synchronizing data to web database.
10-15 09:58:26.328  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30605 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.328  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30605: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases) -
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs D/Sync Images To Web﹕ Synchronizing images to web database.
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) Failed to open database file with errno : 24!
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 32474 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:32474: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase) -
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) Failed to open database file with errno : 24!
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 32474 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.335  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:32474: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase) -
10-15 09:58:26.382  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30605 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.382  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30605: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases) -
10-15 09:58:26.414  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30605 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.414  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30605: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases) -
10-15 09:58:26.445  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30605 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.445  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30605: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases) -
10-15 09:58:26.453  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:341)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:875)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:843)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1213)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:236)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
            at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.DatabaseHandler.SyncToWebGetItems(DatabaseHandler.java:2693)
            at com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.SyncToWeb.onHandleIntent(SyncToWeb.java:57)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-15 09:58:26.460  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:341)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:875)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:843)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1213)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:236)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.DatabaseHandler.getAllWorkList_InspectionResultPicture(DatabaseHandler.java:2512)
            at com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.SyncImages.onHandleIntent(SyncImages.java:59)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-15 09:58:26.460  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=19: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41589930)
10-15 09:58:26.484  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30605 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.484  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30605: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases) -
10-15 09:58:26.531  12045-15370/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[SyncImages]
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:341)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:875)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:843)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1213)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:236)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
            at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.DatabaseHandler.getAllWorkList_InspectionResultPicture(DatabaseHandler.java:2512)
            at com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.SyncImages.onHandleIntent(SyncImages.java:59)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-15 09:58:26.539  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30605 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.539  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30605: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases) -
10-15 09:58:26.539  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteOpenHelper﹕ Couldn't open QIRS_DataBase for writing (will try read-only):
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:341)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:238)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:515)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:207)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:178)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:875)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:843)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1213)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:236)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
            at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.DatabaseHandler.SyncToWebGetItems(DatabaseHandler.java:2693)
            at com.MyCompany.systm.qirs.SyncToWeb.onHandleIntent(SyncToWeb.java:57)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-15 09:58:26.562  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 32474 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.562  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:32474: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase-journal) -
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 32474 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:32474: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase-journal) -
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (10) Failed to open database file with errno : 24!
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 32474 of [00bb9c9ce4]
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:32474: (24) open(/data/data/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs/databases/QIRS_DataBase-journal) -
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-12095/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) statement aborts at 38: [INSERT INTO worklist_inspectionpoint(ID,User_ID,Date_Time,Comments,Pass,List_ID,WorklistStage_ID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)] unable to open database file
10-15 09:58:26.578  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs E/SQLiteLog﹕ (3850) statement aborts at 0: [PRAGMA user_version;] disk I/O error
10-15 09:58:26.585  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=18: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41589930)
10-15 09:58:26.585  12045-15369/com.MyCompany.systm.qirs I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 12045 SIG: 9
```

I know that I have space on disk, 3.55 out of 5.10 Gb. I see an I/O error, but I'm running again the program and it's running without problems. 
In the end, this is service (or to whaterver I need to change it later) needs to be executed when the power is connected to the tablet, because at that point WiFi access will be available and I will need to Synchronize TO the main database AND download the pending data. I have now the broadcast receiver that detects when the power is plugged and displays a Progress Dialog but it does nothing.

So, after ALL this...

1) Any sugestions on what could be happening? (regarding my error messages)

2) Any suggestions on a better aproach to my solution?

3) Bonus points and a beer (or tacos) when you come to Tijuana, how can I launch the service when the power is connected and update a progress dialog with what's being executed

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: 'Failed to open database file with errno : 24!'. What does 24 mean?

Comment: Not sure.. right now I disabled my Intent Services (Sync Images and Sync Data To Web)  to see if those are the one causing me problems, the thing is that I'm not going to be sure of it until one more hour or so, it's a big download of data (aprox 90Mb the size of SQLite Db and 500 Mb of Files to download to the tablet), if I don't get any issues I'll post my Intent Services code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted and did again my code, the logic is more or less the same, I use Services to sync the data to the database every 2 minutes. I found out a way to detect when the tablet is connected (to usb or power) with a BroadCastReceiver. if you want to know how, let me know to share the code

Answer (score 0):

errno 24 is MFILE: "too many open files".

Some code forgets to close some files.

Comment: As you can see in my code I close all the database connections, also on the routine where I create the files I close the streams and the byte array is set to null. I just executed the service without the Intent Services and executed without a problem.. but on my Intent Services I also close my db connections, I just saw that some cursor where not being closed, I added the close to those cursors, but I don't think that's the issue (unless some one tells me the contrary)